# PhD in Cryptography after Master's in Pure Mathematics

Tags: career-path, job-search, job, early-career, cryptography

I have done my Master's in Pure Mathematics.However as we had learnt Cryptography in our Master's Course ,I have developed an inclination towards it.

I have started liking coding theory in Cryptography. I like to write programs.
But I have seen that most  people in Cryptography are from Computer Science background.Should I do PhD in this subject as I am liking it now?

However I am unable to understand is there any prospect of that subject specially since I am a student of Pure Mathematics background.

Will I be able to get a job if I don't remain in Pure Mathematics anymore and start writing codes which are more inclined towards Computer Science.

I am puzzled.Please help me if there is any future of my liking.

Comment: A pure mathematics background can open a lot of doors.  That said, I would strongly suggest you talk to the professors who taught your MA level cryptography courses.  Express your interest, and, particularly being familiar with your work, they should be able to advise you better than we can.

Comment: Cryptography is vast. You can look at the [ePrint archive](http://eprint.iacr.org/curr/) to see what kind of things people are working on now.

Comment: By the way, coding theory and cryptography are really not the same thing, despide being close and sometimes taught together.

Comment: @Jeff;Is it okay to do phd in cryptography after msc in pure maths or that will be difficult to achieve in comparison to students from other streams

Comment: @BenStokes, I'm a moderator on the [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) site. This sort of question would not really be on topic on our site, but I wanted to make you aware of it. You might also checkout our chat room [The Side Channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel). I also suggest you take a look at the [IACR Jobs](https://www.iacr.org/jobs/) site. That should give you a feel for at least some of the jobs out there and what they are looking for.

Comment: Finally, to add to what @fkraiem says, you seem to be referring to coding theory in terms of writing software. That is different from [coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory) as I typically think of it (compression codes, error correction codes, etc). I would call the former software engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice would be to find a way of getting some *research experience* associated with cryptography before committing to the idea of doing a Ph.D. in it. Several advantages to this:

a) you'll know that you'll like working on open problems in cryptography, as opposed to just liking learning about the field in the classroom;

b) it'll give you a sense of the types of research you might want to pursue, which would pave the way for a well-developed statement of purpose in your grad school applications;

c) it could help you make additional useful connections. A Ph.D. application supported by letters from cryptography professors attesting to your research potential in the field would make a lot of sense if you do indeed end up wanting to aim to do a Ph.D. in it.